# make links to point to a textview android

Tags: android

Hello i want to make like a table of contents in my app. I have a textview wich i would like to have some links at the top and when the user clicks one of them, he will be forwarded further down in the same textview. How can i accomplish this, i don't know where to look for info, it should be something like:

```
<a href=”#somePointOnPage”>Go further down</a>


Further down
<a name=”somePointOnPage”></a>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: What do you mean by "forwarded further down"? Scrolling to?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might consider using a WebView and making your content in HTML rather than using a TextView to do this. With the WebView it will work exactly how you want it to already.

To get it working with a TextView you'll have to look into the [Linkify](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/util/Linkify.html) class. The trick will be  to override the link clicks to call the textView.scrollTo(x,y) method which means you'd have to measure out where all of your breaks are in pixels instead of being able to use tags like in html. [Here is another good resource for Linkify](http://www.indelible.org/ink/android-linkify/) in case you want to go this route. [And one more](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2008/03/linkify-your-text.html)

Comment: +1 on WebView. This is how I'm currently doing the documentation for the application I am writing (plus this way I can just send the .html out as well to people who want the application). Built in #-links are so easy to handle.